# Cross domain iframe postMessage не работает

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

Нужно во встроенный `iframe` отправить сообщение.
На родительской странице делаю так:

```
<div id="widget_chat"></div>
<div id="chat_close"></div>
```

```
(function() {
  $('#widget_chat').html('<iframe id="widget_iframe" src="//host/chat/widget.html" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0"></iframe>')

  $(document).on('click', '#chat_close', function () {
    let iframeEl = document.getElementById('widget_iframe')
    let msg = 'msg'
    frameEl.contentWindow.postMessage(msg, '*')
  })
})();
```

На принимающей стороне:

```
$(window).on("message onmessage", function(evt) {
  $('messageContainer').empty();
})
```

либо

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("message", showConsole);
} else {
  window.attachEvent("onmessage", showConsole);
}
```

В функции `showConsole` очистка `div`, `alert` и `console.log`.
В итоге никакой реакции.
Сделал вот так:

```
console.log(frameEl.contentWindow.postMessage(msg, '*')
```

Возвращает `undefined`, хотя у объекта `frameEl.contentWindow` есть метод `postMessage`.

Как можно отследить, на какой стороне проблемы? Или, может, где-то ошибка?
Ошибок в консоли нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, механизм работает, но есть ограничения.
Например, мне не удалось отправить кириллицу, либо длинную строку в `msg`. Так же не удалось в одной строке отправить и текст и числа.

Зато удалось отправить объект и это вполне соответствовало моей задаче.

На родительской странице:

```
let receiver = document.getElementById('widget_iframe').contentWindow
let a = Math.random()
let obj = {
    number: a,
    message: 'onAction'
}
receiver.postMessage(obj, 'http://my.host.ru/');
```

В iframe:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    console.log(e.data.a)
    console.log(e.data.message)
});
```